# Javascript/css working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I am trying to get the following Javascript working in IE 8 to no avail..  Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

The script is for two animated clocks which works all fine and and dandy in EI9, Firefox and Chrome.  EI8 the hands remain unmoved but there are no indicated errors in the browser.. (Safe to assume anything under IE8 will not be working)

```
(function(jQuery)
{
  jQuery.fn.clock = function(options)
  {
    var defaults = {
      offset: '+0',
      type: 'analog'
    };
    var _this = this;
    var opts = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

    setInterval( function() {
      var seconds = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getSeconds();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var sdegree = seconds * 6;
        var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
        var rad = Math.PI/180 * sdegree,
            cos = Math.cos(rad),
            sin = Math.sin(sin);
        jQuery(_this).find(".sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate, "-ms-transform" : srotate, "-sand-transform" : srotate,
                                        '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+cos+", M12="+(-sin)+", M21="+sin+", M22="+cos+", SizingMethod='auto expand')"});
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".sec").html(seconds);
      }
    }, 1000 );

    setInterval( function() {
      var hours = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getHours();
      var mins = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getMinutes();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
        var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";
        var rad = Math.PI/180 * hdegree,
            cos = Math.cos(rad),
            sin = Math.sin(sin);
        jQuery(_this).find(".hour").css({"-moz-transform" : hrotate, "-webkit-transform" : hrotate, "-ms-transform" : hrotate, "-sand-transform" : hrotate,
                                         '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+cos+", M12="+(-sin)+", M21="+sin+", M22="+cos+", SizingMethod='auto expand')"});
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".hour").html(hours+':');
      }
      var meridiem = hours<12?'AM':'PM';
      jQuery(_this).find('.meridiem').html(meridiem);
    }, 1000 );

    setInterval( function() {
      var mins = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getMinutes();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var mdegree = mins * 6;
        var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";
        var rad = Math.PI/180 * mdegree,
            cos = Math.cos(rad),
            sin = Math.sin(sin);
        jQuery(_this).find(".min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate, "-ms-transform" : mrotate, "-sand-transform" : mrotate,
                                        '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+cos+", M12="+(-sin)+", M21="+sin+", M22="+cos+", SizingMethod='auto expand')"});                
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".min").html(mins+':');
      }
    }, 1000 );
  }
})(jQuery);


jQuery.calcTime = function(offset) {
  d = new Date();
  utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
  return nd;
};
```

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: @Kolink No errors are being thrown.  Amended my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ms-filter` is specific to IE9. In IE8 and below, the property was just `filter`.

IE9 supports transforms under `-ms-transform`, so you could alter your code to set `-ms-transform` for IE9 and `filter` for IE<=8.

Comment: Thanks for that - the good news is, I finally have some animation!  Bad news is - it's not exactly doing the desired rotation..

Comment: Your matrix is probably incorrect... I think you meant `sin = Math.sin(rad)`, where you wrote `Math.sin(sin)` instead.

Comment: Thanks again!  Bit more movement in the rotation is still very odd - not quite sure where I am going wrong

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17360036/932282 for a working example